# Flash Builder 4 Standard Profiling & Unit testing alternatives

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I want to profile and unit test my application in Flash Builder 4 Standard. Adobe says I need to upgrade to the Premium version but I can't pay the money they want right now..

Are there any alternatives for unit testing and profiling?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FlexUnit 4 does'nt need Premium version of Flash Builder.

As for profiling, are you sure the Profiler is not part of the standard version? I know the Network Monitor is only in the Premium version, but tought the Profiler was in both.

**UPDATE** Has been confirmed in the comments that Profiler is FB4 Premium only

Comment: When I press the profile button it says to visit adobe to learn about FB4 Premium...

Comment: I can verify that it is not part of the standard version as chchrist says.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder Premium provides a FlexUnit integration but you can unit test without it.
About profiling, there is an open source alternative called [FlashPreloaderProfiler](http://jpauclair.net/flashpreloadprofiler/)